# Nginx redirect https to http based on browser language

Tags: nginx

Since my server is far away, I'd like to redirect https to http when browser language is Chinese (zh). Following code work well in Apache:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^zh [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But I cannot figure out its Nginx equivalent on my new VPS server. Current nginx.conf is as follows:

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
        listen 88;
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
    root /www/wwwroot/mysite.com;

    #SSL-START SSL related configuration, do NOT delete or modify the next line of commented-out 404 rules
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    ssl_certificate    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key    /www/server/panel/vhost/cert/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+CHACHA20-draft:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=0";
    error_page 497  https://$host$request_uri;
    #SSL-END

    ......
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if you split the config into two `server` blocks. One with `listen 80;` and one with `listen 443 ssl;`. That would satisfy the `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on` condition.

The remaining condition can be implemented with an `if` block.

For example:

```
index index.php index.html index.htm default.php default.htm default.html;
root /www/wwwroot/mysite.com;

server
{
    listen 80;
    listen 88;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    ......
}
server
{
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    #SSL-START
    ... 
    #SSL-END

    if ($http_accept_language ~* ^zh) {
        return 301 http://$host$request_uri;
    }

    ......
}
```

To avoid duplicated code, some directives which are common to all `server` blocks, can be moved into the outer block. Other common code can be placed into a separate file and included into both `server` blocks using an [`include` statement](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include).

Answer (score 0):

It works great. Thank you, Richard.
At the same time, following instruction on https://gist.github.com/jrom/1760790 I tried to add following code below #SSL-END without splitting server:

```
if ($scheme = https) { 
    set $test A; 
}
if ($http_accept_language ~* ^zh) { 
    set $test "${test}B"; 
}
if ($test = AB) {
    return 301 http://$server_name$request_uri;
    break;
}
```

It also works and seems simpler, but I'm not sure if there exist any negative impact?